# independent random variable

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question about independence of two random variables. Say X and Y are two random variables, if I know that X is independent of I(Y>y), for any real value y, where I() is the indicator function. Can we conclude that X is independent of Y ? How to understand this problem based on measure theory?

Answer (score 1):

One definition of $X$ and $Y$ being independent is that $P(X > a \land Y > b) = P(X > a)P(Y > b)$ for any $a, b$. So you may conclude independence using what you have:

$$P(X > a \land Y > b) = P(X > a \land I(Y > b) > \frac 1 2) = \\=P(X > a)P(I(Y > b) > \frac 1 2) = P(X > a)P(Y > b)$$

Regarding your latter question: $P(X > a)$ can be interpreted, for instance, as the (probability) measure of the subset $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) > a\}$ of the probability space $\Omega$. The other expressions work similarly. Does this answer your question?

Comment: The event $E$ occurs if and only if $I(E) = 1$ - that is the definition of the indicator function. Since the indicator function can only be $0$ or $1$, being equal to $1$ is the same as being greater than $1/2$.

Comment: Oh, that's right! But if we are thinking about it based on measure theory, what is the sigma field generated by I(Y>y)?

Comment: Let $f(\omega) = I(Y > y)(\omega)$. Then $f^{-1}(A)$ depends only on whether $0 \in A$ and whether $1 \in A$. One concludes that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f$ is just $\{\varnothing, \Omega, \{Y>y\}, \{Y\le y\}\}$.

Comment: So if X is independent of Y, that is to say, the sigma field generated by X is indep of that generated by Y. In this case, what's the relationship between $\sigma$(Y) and the field you gave above?

Comment: I am almost sure (pun unintended?) that this is true: $\sigma(Y) = \sigma(\{I(Y > y)\}_{y \in \Bbb{R}})$. That is, it's the field $\sigma$-generated by all those tiny fields.

Comment: right. What I am thinking is that if we want to show $\sigma$(X) is indep of $\sigma$(Y), how can we use the known conditions that $\sigma$(X) is indep of $\sigma$(I(Y>y)), for any y ?

Comment: You can show it by "induction" on the construction of $\sigma(Y)$. It is given that $A \in \sigma(X)$ is independent of $B \in \sigma(I(Y > y))$ for any *specific* $y$. Now use that if $A$ is independent of $B$ then it's independent of $\Omega \setminus B$ and also that if it's independent of $B_1, B_2, ...$ then it's independent of their union. This means it's independent of a $\sigma$-closed family...

Answer (score 0):

QUOTE:

> if I know that X is independent of I(Y>y), for any real value y, where I() is the indicator function. Can we conclude that X is independent of Y ?

END QUOTE

This is ambiguous:

> If there is any value of $y$ for which the indicator variable $I(Y>y)$ is independent of $X$, then . . . .

versus

> If it is the caswe that for any value of $y$, the indicator variable $I(Y>y)$ is independent of $X$, then . . . .

There is a difference in meaning.  Just changing "any" to "every" in your original phrasing fully disambiguates it.

And then the bottom line is "yes".